# Textbox inputscope winrt - numbers only similar to 'enter your password' on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I would like to use the numbers only keypad on winrt like the one displayed on windows phone 'enter your password' screen? Even if this is one line of keys horizontally aligned.

can it be done? It doesn't look like a standard offering in the enum...

Is it possible to create custom input scopes for c#/xaml/winrt?

thanks

Comment: just to be clear: I have a textbox, using c#, xaml and winrt, I want the input scope for that textbox to bring up a keypad that only has numbers 0 - 9, similar to the one on the password keypad on windows phone
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only InputScope that you can use is **Number**, you can't create your own. The only solution I can advise you here is handling TextChanged event, and using UInt32.TryParse() (as you don't need negative numbers, or you can just use NumberStyles.None).